# Javascript function blocking working on just 1 button, not on all

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, menu, toggle

I have a Javascript function which toggles a menu. That is working for the first post (I am using `Wordpress`), but now, on the `comments`, it does not work c.q. toggle. I edited `wp_list_comments` and putted these anchors on every comment, but if I click on them, they don't do a thing.

This is the function I am using:

```
function showElement(layer){
var myLayer = document.getElementById(layer);
if(myLayer.style.display=="none"){
myLayer.style.display="block";
myLayer.backgroundPosition="top";
} else {
myLayer.style.display="none";
}
}

 document.getElementById("share-bar").onclick = function(){
        javascript:showElement('v-menu');
    };
```

PS: when  I put this script inline, in the .php file, it works, but now how I want it to work. If I click on this anchor at a comment, it will open the menu from the first post. So I can't open multiple menu's at the same time and the right one....

Can someone help me fixing this problems please?

PS: I checked console and there are no errors or whatsoever.
PS: I thought it would have to do with ID/Class, so used `getElementsByClassName()`, but that did not work too.

Here is the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uKVwG/

Comment: Please pay more attention to the "spelling" of the code. There are several typos in your fiddle...

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById` can only return ONE element. An html `id` is unique by definition.

You should use classes instead!

```
document.getElementsByClassName('share').onclick = function(){
    showElement(this.getElementsByClassName('v-menu')[0]);
}
```

Comment: Did you see my post? I said earlier that I did tried that, but this time, it won't work at all (even the first post).

Comment: Of course you need to set the appropriate classes on the elements

Comment: Obviously, that is done already. It didn't work. It does nothing at all.

Comment: I created the jsFiddle... http://jsfiddle.net/uKVwG/ --> if you change the ClassName and Class to Id, than it will work. But as you  said, that's not what you want.

Comment: As Teemu says: that's not working at all. I hope someone can find the problem.

Comment: ok it's a typo. It's getElementsByClassName.
Anyway it's a real pleasure to help you man... (Irony)
PS : Learn JS and CSS a bit more and think, just an advice

Comment: lol. I solved it already :) It's pathetic that you are giving me a downvote. Really, that's very cheap.